# how to call api after refresh token with using react-fetching-library reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

**Hi, i m working on project with reactjs and using tokens and refresh token. after 401 error i m able to call APIs. APIs response showing 200 in network tab but data not updating in components.**

**refresh token call**

```
const responseInterceptor = (client: any) => async (action:any, response:any) => {
      const tokens = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tokens'));
      if (response.status === 401) {
        return fetch(api.com/refresh_Token, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            refreshToken: tokens.refreshToken,
            Accept: 'application.json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ ucc_pan: "string" }),
        })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(response => {
            console.log(response, "response33");
            setItem("tokens", JSON.stringify(response.data));
            // Update the original request with the new access token and retry
            const updatedRequest = {
              ...action,
              headers: {
                ...action.headers,
                accessToken: response.data.accessToken,
              },
            };
            return client(updatedRequest);
          });
      }
      return response;
    };
    
    const clientOption = createClient({
      requestInterceptors: [requestHostInterceptor(API_URL)],
      responseInterceptors: [responseInterceptor],
    });
    
    export const client = clientOption;
    
    export const ClientContextProvider = CCP;
```